# Facebook API - Using multiple requests in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, facebook-graph-api

I have written an app that I am not happy with. Essentially it queries the Facebook API in a few ways:

1. Gets a list of all posts
2. Retrieves each post
3. Retrieves each posts comments

I can get a list of all posts in 1 API request, but I've nested each subsequent API request in a loop. I'd like to do this all at once, and is there any reading on sending all the requests at once, and then handling the API requests as they come in?

I'm looking for reading, GEMS, suggestions at strategies.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "sending all the requests at once, and then handling the API requests as they come in?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answers here: [What is the preferred way of performing non blocking I/O in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468471/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-performing-non-blocking-i-o-in-ruby)

Good options seems to be:

- [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus)
- [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) + [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request)