# Making a non blocking HTTP request in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, rest, nonblocking

Is anyone aware of a way to make outgoing non blocking HTTP requests from within Rails?  I will need the response body eventually and am trying to avoid bringing up new frameworks to keep things simple.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the preferred way of performing non blocking I/O in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468471/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-performing-non-blocking-i-o-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def async_post
  Thread.new do
    uri = URI('https://somewhere.com/do_something')
    response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'param1' => '1', 'param2' => '2')
    # do something with the response
  end
  # Execution continues before the response is received
end
```

Answer (score -1):

To simulate the non-blocking part, set a low read_timeout. Also be prepared to catch the resulting timeout error:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

http.read_timeout = 1

begin
  http.request(request)
rescue Timeout::Error => e
end
```

I don't know of a basic rails mechanism that will both make a non-blocking call and receive the response. Rails is very much tied to the request/response cycle, so usually the basic controller execution path will have ended before the HTTP call returns.

Comment: "low timeout" != "non-blocking"

Comment: Absolutely nothing about a low timeout "simulates" non-blocking IO. Now you're doing blocking IO with tons of timeouts and failed requests, the worst of all worlds.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for "background jobs" or "background workers." There are a variety of gems for this. [This blog post](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/background-jobs-in-ruby-on-rails/) has a good overview of what's out there. [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) is very popular right now.